# How to change the color of a scrollbar in a DataGrid in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I want to change the color of the vertical and horizontal scrollbar. But I'm unable to find the solution.

I tried to Google it out already but I got tired how to do it.

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: Try This:> [Customizing the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171618.aspx)